# How to make image "hang over" above background?

Tags: css

I am more a web programmer than a designer, but currently my job requires me to know more about web design. Sorry if the question is naive to the pros.

Stuck in this problem for hours, don't know what to do...

Please go the my blog and check the bottom part: [my blog](http://chenximao.net/blog)

It has a wax seal style rss feed image, with ribbon. I want to have the ribbon lie above the background color (the parchment paper, that is) so to display the wooden background. But I failed in this for hours. Done some research online and tried several different ways. Still with no luck.

The visual effect I want to achieve can be found on this webpage: The image of  the father and his child illustrates what I want to have : http://www.havocinspired.co.uk/

Please use FireBug and check my css stylesheet. I use a tool called Artiseer to help me get around the fundamentals. So perhaps that's how everything looks so messy under the hood.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You'll probably get better/quicker answers over at http://doctype.com

Comment: Hi Jim: thanks for your tip. I will go and have a look there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving it a negative `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Tried again, this time found the right div tag to give it a negative bottom margin! It works!

Comment: I'm sure that worked, but it's more sloppiness on top of sloppiness. My answer takes away some of the bad code to fix the problem.

Just my opinion. No offense.

Comment: I do take offense. How is that bad code? It's very clear. It indicates that it is supposed to float outside of its parent div, exactly as it appears. It's better than adding a ton of HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your html to this:

```
<div class="art-Footer">
  <div class="art-Footer-background">
    <div class="art-Footer-inner">
      <a href="http://chenximao.net/blog/feed/" class="art-rss-tag-icon" title="RSS"></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then change your styles (change the relevant styles to what you see below, or compare whats below to what you have to find what I took out):

> .art-Footer { margin:20px auto 0;
>   position:relative; width:884px;
>   z-index:0; }
>
> .art-Footer .art-Footer-background {
>   background-image:url(images/Footer.png);
>   background-repeat:repeat; bottom:45px;
>   height:75px; left:0;
>   vertical-align:top; width:884px;
>   z-index:-1; }
>
> .art-Footer .art-Footer-inner {
>   padding:5px; position:relative;
>   text-align:center; z-index:0; }
>
> .art-rss-tag-icon {
>   background-image:url(images/rsssealicon.png);
>   background-position:left top;
>   background-repeat:no-repeat;
>   display:block; float:left;
>   height:100px; margin:0 -120px 0 50px;
>   position:relative; top:-11px;
>   width:62px; }

Comment: http://i35.tinypic.com/2vwibna.jpg

Hi George. Above is how it looks under my FireFox 3.5 browser.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I was looking at the wrong 'wax seal'.

Ok, well, your footer looks a bit overcomplicated to me. That's ok.

Put the .art-Footer-background around .art-Footer-inner. On the .art-Footer, make it margin 0 auto; and take off the overflow:hidden, take the position:absolute off of .art-Footer-background. 

Now you can move the ribbon around with top and left.
Try to avoid things like overflow:hidden, negative magins, things like that. They get confusing. Use them sparingly.

Is that more like what youre looking for?